# Find high - low for a particular intraday time interval

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to find the high/low of a particular candle in tradingview. For e.g. I need to know the high of the candle that formed between 10:00-10:15. Is there a way to execute that in pine script

I have already tried looking around, but could not find an example code doing this.

Something I've tried:

```
t1 = time(period, "1000-1015")
session_open = na(t1) ? false : true

if (session_open)
    ll = low
    hh = high
```

Comment: Show us the code you tried.

Comment: I was trying to do something like this:

t1 = time(period, "1000-1015")

session_open = na(t1) ? false : true

if (session_open)
    ll = low
    hh = high

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're looking something like this:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

locHigh = 0.0
locLow = 0.0

h = security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", high, lookahead=true)
l = security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", low, lookahead=true)

if hour == 10 and minute == 0
    locHigh := h
    locLow := l
else
    locHigh := locHigh[1]
    locLow := locLow[1]

plot(locHigh)
plot(locLow)
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot.